# SQL Server : stored procedure IFNULL check

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

```
Solution_id (Primary key, Int)
Col1 (varchar)
Col2 (varchar)
Col3 (varchar)
Col4 (varchar)
Col5 (varchar)
```

I am writing a stored procedure to update this table. There are 6 input parameters for the above 6 columns.

```
@Attached_File1 VARCHAR(MAX),
@Attached_File2 VARCHAR(MAX),
@Attached_File3 VARCHAR(MAX),
@Attached_File4 VARCHAR(MAX),
@Attached_File5 VARCHAR(MAX),
@Ticket_ID BIGINT
```

I want to write a SQL query which will update the table with the values specified in the input parameters. BUT I must not overwrite the attachment columns with null. I mean I need to use only those parameters which contains data.

For example, if the table has a row

```
[10, "aaa", "bbb", "efg", null, null]
```

and the input parameters are

```
(10, null, null, "mno", "ddd", null)
```

then after the update the row will become

```
[10, "aaa", "bbb", "mno", "ddd", null]
```

How to check for null/empty strings and generate the update query accordingly to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this something like you're after?

```
UPDATE mytable
SET Col1 = ISNULL(@Attached_File1, Col1),
    Col2 = ISNULL(@Attached_File2, Col2),
    Col3 = ISNULL(@Attached_File3, Col3),
    Col4 = ISNULL(@Attached_File4, Col4),
    Col5 = ISNULL(@Attached_File5, Col5)
WHERE Solution_id = @Ticket_ID
```

`ISNULL` takes two values, if the first one is not null then it is used, otherwise the 2nd value is used.

[See MSDN for more information on `ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

---

**Update**

I've just noticed your comment at the end, which talks about empty strings...

> How to check for null/empty strings and generate the update query accordingly to achieve this?

In which case, you could do the following...

```
UPDATE mytable
SET Col1 = ISNULL(NULLIF(@Attached_File1,''), Col1),
    Col2 = ISNULL(NULLIF(@Attached_File2,''), Col2),
    Col3 = ISNULL(NULLIF(@Attached_File3,''), Col3),
    Col4 = ISNULL(NULLIF(@Attached_File4,''), Col4),
    Col5 = ISNULL(NULLIF(@Attached_File5,''), Col5)
WHERE Solution_id = @Ticket_ID
```

This uses the `NULLIF` statement which takes two values, if the first value is the same as the second value, then NULL is returned, otherwise it returns the first value.

[See MSDN for more information on `NULLIF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx)

Comment: Hi , Thanks for your answer but when my parameter is null it is over-writing the existing table value to NULL .

Comment: Hi @user1681514, I am just one of 3 people who gave you an identical solution, which would point to a problem with a different part of your stored procedure (or maybe the code that is using that stored procedure)

Comment: Looks like its something else causing the issue like you said . Thanks for your help ! I will try to figure out

Comment: @user1681514 - check out my updated answer, especially if you are sending empty strings as parameters. (Remember that an empty string - both in database and normal programming - is **not** the same as null)

Comment: Hi Freefall .. Thanks for the answer ! It works the way I want now

Answer (score 2):

```
update  YourTable
set     col1 = isnull(@Attached_File1, col1)
,       col2 = isnull(@Attached_File2, col2)
,       col3 = isnull(@Attached_File3, col3)
,       ...
where   Solution_ID = @Ticket_ID
```

If the parameters can contain empty strings, consider @freefaller's answer.  If it can contain whitepsace, try:

```
set     col1 = case 
               when @Attached_File1 like '%[^ \t\r\n]%' then @Attached_File1 
               else col1 
               end
,       col2 = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking only for Nulls, not for empty strings:

```
UPDATE 
    tableX
SET
    Col1 = COALESCE(@Attached_File1, Col1),
    ...
    Col5 = COALESCE(@Attached_File5, Col5)
WHERE
    Solution_id = @Ticket_ID ;
```

Comment: I tried this but if my Input Parameter has null value . It is over-writing the column-value to null

Comment: Sorry, missed the `@`. Are you sure it overwrites when there are nulls in the parameters? On when there are empty strings?

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
UPDATE Table
SET
    Col1 = ISNULL(@Attached_File1, Col1),
    Col2 = ISNULL(@Attached_File1, Col2),
    Col3 = ISNULL(@Attached_File1, Col3),
    Col4 = ISNULL(@Attached_File1, Col4),
    Col5 = ISNULL(@Attached_File1, Col5),
WHERE
    Solution_Id = @Ticket_ID
```